# How to speed up stacked queries in Django using caching

Tags: python, django, django-models, optimization, django-queryset

Current in my project, I have a layer of models as such:

- **Sensor class:** which stores different sensors
- **Entry class:** which stores whenever a new data entry happens
- **Data class:** which stores data pairs for each entry.

Generally, that additional class was used since I have different fields for different sensors and I wanted to store them in one database, so how I was doing that was through two methods, one for entry to get the data for it, and one in the sensor as follows:

```
class Data(models.Model):
    key = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    value = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    entry = models.ForeignKey(Entry, on_delete=CASCADE, related_name="dataFields")

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id) + "-" + self.key + ":" + self.value
```

```
class Entry(models.Model):
    time = models.DateTimeField()
    sensor = models.ForeignKey(Sensor, on_delete=CASCADE, related_name="entriesList")

    def generateFields(self, field=None):
        """
        Generate the fields by merging the Entry and data fields.

        Outputs a dictionary which contains all fields.
        """

        if field is None:
            field_set = self.dataFields.all()
        else:
            field_set = self.dataFields.filter(key=field)

        output = {"timestamp": self.time.timestamp()}

        for key, value in field_set.values_list("key", "value"):
            try:
                floated = float(value)
                isnan = math.isnan(floated)
            except (TypeError, ValueError):
                continue

            if isnan:
                return None
            else:
                output[key] = floated

        return output
```

```
class Sensor(models.Model):
.
.
.
    def generateData(self, fromTime, toTime, field=None):
        fromTime = datetime.fromtimestamp(fromTime)
        toTime = datetime.fromtimestamp(toTime)
        entries = self.entriesList.filter(time__range=(toTime, fromTime)).order_by(
            "time"
        )
        output = []
        for entry in entries:
            value = entry.generateFields(field)
            if value is not None:
                output.append(value)
        return output
```

After trying to troubleshoot the issues of time (as running this query for a ~5000-10000 entries took too long, almost 10 seconds!), i found that most of the time (about 95%) was spent on the method for `generateFields()`, I've been looking at options for caching it (by using cached_property), using different methods but none have really worked so far.

Is there a method to store the results of `generateFields()` in the database automatically upon saving the model perhaps? Or possibly just saving the results of the reverse-query `self.dataFields.all()`? I can figure out that's the main culprit since for 5000 entries, there are 25000 data fields on average at least.

(Thanks to Jacinator for the notes and improvements) above is the code after Jacinator's changes, but the issue (and the question) still stands at large, as caching the fields would speed up the process by almost 25-50 times(!!) which is critical when my actual dataset can be much larger (1~ minute to run a query isnt really acceptable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is how I would consider writing `generateFields`.

```py
class Entry(models.Model):
    ...

    def generateFields(self, field=None):
        """
        Generate the fields by merging the Entry and data fields.

        Outputs a dictionary which contains all fields.
        """

        if field is None:
            field_set = self.dataFields.all()
        else:
            field_set = self.dataFields.filter(key=field)

        output = {"timestamp": self.time.timestamp()}

        for key, value in field_set.values_list("key", "value"):
            try:
                floated = float(value)
                isnan = math.isnan(floated)
            except (TypeError, ValueError):
                continue

            if isnan:
                return None
            else:
                output[key] = floated

        return output
```

First, I'm going to avoid comparing the field (if it's provided) in Python. I can use the queryset `.filter` to pass that off to the SQL.

```py
        if field is None:
            field_set = self.dataFields.all()
        else:
            field_set = self.dataFields.filter(key=field)
```

Second, I'm using `QuerySet.values_list` to retrieve the values from the entries. I could be wrong (please correct me if so), but I think this also passes off the attribute retrieval to the SQL. I don't actually know if it's faster, but I suspect it might be.

```py
        for key, value in field_set.values_list("key", "value"):
```

I've restructured the try/except block, but that has less to do with increasing the speed and more to do with making it explicit what errors are being caught and what lines are raising them.

```py
            try:
                floated = float(value)
                isnan = math.isnan(floated)
            except (TypeError, ValueError):
                continue
```

The lines outside of the try/except now should be problem free.

```py
            if isnan:
                return None
            else:
                output[key] = floated
```

I'm a little unfamiliar with [`QuerySet.prefetch_related`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related), but I think adding it to this line would also help.

```py
        entries = self.entriesList.filter(time__range=(toTime, fromTime)).order_by(
            "time").prefetch_related("dataFields")
```

Comment: I will try out the suggestions here, but I have a suspecion it might not be what I am looking for exactly, but I am going to give it a try anyway. The main issue is that `self.dataFields.all()` is just being called too many times, so my database is running 25000(!) queries, when if this data is cached or stored it doesnt need to run any of those. I do appreciate the suggestions for the code however.

Comment: That's what the bit for `QuerySet.prefetch_related` is for. I'm not super familiar but I think it will collapse a whole bunch of those queries into one.

Comment: I looked into it earlier and couldn't see how it can be applied, but I will look more into it and try something out. The changes suggested here *did* improve the speed by a bit, around 5-10% (which is great), but I do feel I will need either the prefetch to work or find a major breakthrough (as my dataset will need to run this function for sometimes 5-10x this size which would be problematic.

Comment: And interstingly enough, adding `entries = self.entriesList.filter(time__range=(toTime, fromTime)).order_by(
            "time").prefetch_related("dataFields")` slowed down the query by 20%!

Comment: That's too bad. I guess I don't understand that as well as I thought I did.

Comment: I still appreciate the other help here, the `for key, value in field_set.values_list("key", "value"):` suggestion especially has been quite helpful! Thanks again :)

Comment: Accepted this answer as your tips has helped me a lot, cheers mate.

Answer (score 0):

While it is not the perfect solution, below is the approach I am using at the moment (I am still looking for a better solution, but for this case I believe this might be useful to others who face the exact same situation as me here.)

- I am using [django-picklefield](https://github.com/gintas/django-picklefield) to store the cachedData, declaring it as:

```
from picklefield.fields import PickledObjectField

.
.
.
class Entry(models.Model):
    time = models.DateTimeField()
    sensor = models.ForeignKey(Sensor, on_delete=CASCADE, related_name="entriesList")
    cachedValues = PickledObjectField(null=True)
```

- Next, I am adding a property to both generate the value, and return it as:

```
    @property
    def data(self):
        if self.cachedValues is None:
            fields = self.generateFields()
            self.cachedValues = fields
            self.save()
            return fields
        else:
            return self.cachedValues
```

- Normaly, this field will be set automatically when new data is added, however since I have a large amount of data already present, while I can wait until its accessed (as future access will be much faster), i decided to quick-index it by running this:

```
def mass_set(request):
    clear = lambda: os.system("clear")
    entries = Entry.objects.all()
    length = len(entries)
    for count, entry in enumerate(entries):
        _ = entry.data
        clear()
        print(f"{count}/{length} done")
```

Finally, below are the benchmarks for a set of 2230 fields running on my local development machine, measuring the main loop as such:

```
    def generateData(self, fromTime, toTime, field=None):
        fromTime = datetime.fromtimestamp(fromTime)
        toTime = datetime.fromtimestamp(toTime)
        # entries = self.entriesList.filter().order_by('time')
        entries = self.entriesList.filter(time__range=(toTime, fromTime)).order_by(
            "time"
        )
        output = []
        totalTimeLoop = 0
        totalTimeGenerate = 0
        stage1 = time.time()
        stage2 = time.time()
        for entry in entries:
            stage1 = time.time()
            totalTimeLoop += stage1 - stage2
            # Value = entry.generateFields(field)
            value = entry.data
            stage2 = time.time()
            totalTimeGenerate += stage2 - stage1
            if value is not None:
                output.append(value)
        print(f"Total time spent generating the loop: {totalTimeLoop}")
        print(f"Total time spent creating the fields: {totalTimeGenerate}")
        return output
```

**Before:**

- Loop Generation Time: 0.1659650
- Fields Generation Time: 3.1726377

**After:**

- Loop Generation Time: 0.1614456
- Fields Generation Time: 0.0032608

About a ***thousand-fold*** decrease in fields generation time, and in overall time a **20x speed increase**

As for the cons, there are two mainly:

While applying it to my dataset currently (with 167 thousand fields), it takes a considerable amount of time to update, it took around 23 minutes on my local machine, and is expected to take about an hour or two on live servers. However this is a one-time process as all future entries will be added automatically with minimum performance effect with adding the following lines:

```
            _ = newEntry.data
            newEntry.save()
```

The other is database size, while went from **100.8 MB** to **132.9 MB**, a significant increase of **31%** that can be problematic for a database a few scales larger than mine, but a good enough solution small/medium DBs where storage is less important than speed